# Cloaking Emails does not work

Tags: emails

I found this article about cloaking emails http://docs.joomla.org/How_to_cloak_email_addresses

This is not working for me :(. If I open an article and change to the source-code view and paste in JHtml::_('email.cloak', 'demo@example.com'); the code is interpreted as text not as email link - not to mention that it is uncloaked.

Can someone tell me what I have to do to make that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, please ensure you are using the latest version of your Joomla build, so either 2.5.24 or 3.3.3 as there was a bug fixed for the email cloak in both the latest versions.

You cannot simply paste PHP into your text editor, this will not work. For Joomla to process PHP or other languages in the editor, you must use a 3rd party plugin such as [Sourcerer](http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/sourcerer).

Answer (score 2):

The code you're trying to use (`JHtml::_('email.cloak','demo@example.com');` is not meant to be used within articles. The page you linked to states clearly:

> Joomla has inbuilt email cloaking functionality that can be called
>   **within a component or module template**

But there is an email cloaking plugin included in your Joomla installation, look for `Content - Email Cloaking` in the Joomla Plugin Manager and enable it if necessary. Or check the [Joomla Extensions Directory.](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/email-protection)